# EF 4.2 DbContext multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a EF DataRepository Pattern, which I designed from the ground up, and works great when working with EF through the web applications that use it, but I have been tasked with producing an WCF API version of my system which works fine when only retrieving data.

When I try to create new objects (these are created within the web service method and are not serilaized from the request) I get the following issue:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker
```

Now I had seen this previously when developing the system, but this had been because I was creating a new Context for every call, I remedied this by throwing my context into **HttpContext.Current.Items** which as I say works great in the web applications, but now when I a call the code to give me the Context, HttpContext is Null (as expected) so the code would again generate a new Context for each call within the method.

To fix this I gave my service providers the ability to send a Context (as a parameter) when initialising the service provider. 
I then declare the Context at the start of the method, which means all calls within this method use the same context.

But I am still getting the same issue?

Sample code:

```
public MyObject DoSomething()
{
    var dbContext = new myContext();

    var foos = new FooHelper(dbContext).GetAllFoos();

    var bah = new bah();
    bah.Foo = foos.First();
    bah.title = "youre a real object";

    new bahHelper(dbContext).Create(bah);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to dispose the context properly and test if the error disappears then:

```
public MyObject DoSomething()
{
    using (var dbContext = new myContext())
    {
        var foos = new FooHelper(dbContext).GetAllFoos();

        var bah = new bah();
        bah.Foo = foos.First();
        bah.title = "youre a real object";

        new bahHelper(dbContext).Create(bah);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would make no difference, as the error occurs on the Create in this method not after it. I have however tried adding dbContext.dispose() in after each use this returns the same error.

Comment: @JamesStuddart: Do you know what the error message means? "*multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker*" means that more than one context instance is involved, i.e. there is an entity which refers to (a not disposed) context1 (with POCOs usually through lazy loading or change tracking proxies) and you attach this entity to context2. It's not the context you are passing into `bahHelper` that may cause trouble but a reference to an older context (hidden in some entity proxy) from a former request or processing and that is not disposed. So, disposing makes a difference.

Comment: @JamesStuddart: If your code does not rely on lazy loading or proxy change tracking can you try to disable proxy creation, for example in the `MyContext` constructor: `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`. It would be interesting to see if the error persists...

Comment: I understand what the error means, thanks. I do use lazy loading but a single context is used through the methods. This is apparent as the method works when called within the project but it doesnt work when call via the webservice. Its bizarre to say the least.

Comment: Me.IsRedFaced = True; I have found the issue, I have one call to a helper which I had neglected to/over looked when providing the dbContext. Its amazing how you become code blind after spending two days looking at the code. Thanks for your help. I was on the right tracks, but you made me look at the issue with fresh eyes and go back over the code to ensure I had done everything. For that reason I'll mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

When I found such issue, in my case I filled out my model with entity that was created by another context, so I just ignored that entity and recreated it again using that Id. Just make sure that you create all of your entities (including nested) in the same context.